# Have to wait 3 seconds before rename file after copy or move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, file-io

I have a strange behavior with simple PHP script.

When I try to rename a file after `move_uploaded_file` (same behavior with copy), it fail because the file isn't is the new folder (whereas, `move_uploaded_file` return `true`)
BUT, if a wait 2 ou 3 seconds after the `move_uploaded_file`, the rename work fine.

This code FAIL :

```
$result = move_uploaded_file($temp_name, 'new_folder/'.$filename);
echo $result; //=> True
$result = rename('new_folder/'.$filename, 'new_new_folder/'.$filename);
echo $result; //=> False
```

This code WORK :

```
$result = move_uploaded_file($temp_name, 'new_folder/'.$filename);
echo $result; //=> True
sleep(3);
$result = rename('new_folder/'.$filename, 'new_new_folder/'.$filename);
echo $result; //=> True
```

I try to list files of new_folder just before call rename and in the first case, it don't return the file, and in the second case, the file is listed.

What happens there?

I use PHP-FPM and xcache. (No change with xcache disabled)

Comment: What is the size of the file?

Comment: At least 1MB. Indeed it doesn't occur with smaller files.

Comment: It's related to the behavior of move_uploaded_file. Your next code is parsed before the file is completely moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, 'new_folder/'.$filename)) {
   echo $filename;
   $result = rename('new_folder/'.$filename, 'new_new_folder/'.$filename);
   echo $filename;
   echo $result;
   //=> True
 }
```